# what the best options for CURLOPT_ENCODING in PHP

Tags: php

am facing issue of fetching data from big file of multi weblinks.

in my code use :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
```

i used it to speed the curl request,
i tested my code on a few links and its works fine but after using the big file i get a bad results .

As i understand it used to compress the data while retrieve. so i used it to fast the curl request. 
could it make any error in data retrieve like that the site not using gzip?

my code also using fork with no sleep time, maybe the problem from the fork ?

```
$pid = @pcntl_fork();
$execute++;
if ($execute >= $maxproc)
{
    while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) 
    {
        $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
        $execute =0;
        //usleep(250000);
        //sleep(1);
        //echo " [$ipkey]  Child $status completed\n";
    }
}
if (!$pid) 
{   
    do
    exit;
}
```

any one have idea where the probliem is ?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and provide an explanation of what "bad results" means for you?

Comment: As about the question in the title, the option sets the `Accept-Encoding` request encoding so, if the server supports such transparent HTTP compression encoding, it can send compressed data back.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález my bad results is that from 1 million links it gets only 7 true results .
and most the links have my search "keyword" in source .